# How do I pass a value returned from one dataset as parameters to a second dataset to return a value from the second dataset in a cell expression?

Tags: reporting-services, bids

How do I pass two dynamic values returned from one dataset as parameters to another dataset to return one row of a second dataset in a cell?

For each cell in a header row I need to determine A) Which column to get based off the meal period, and then B) take that value and pass it and another parameter to a query to get one of the columns (I'll take first) from the query.

I am already using cascading parameters, but I'm not sure if or how to use them in this scenario.

Example:

```
@SalesReceipt
@MealPeriod (A cascaded parameter. There should be one meal period per receipt)
```

Expression in an example cell:

```
=IIF(Parameters!@MealPeriod.value = "Lunch", Fields!Burger_Lunch_Type.value, Fields!Burger_Dinner_Type.value)
```

That returns either the lunch or dinner Type from a fact table, depending on meal period.

Given the Type and Item ID I need to get a value from another query or dataset and add that text to the cell expression.  So the expression would look something like:

```
=IIF(Parameters!@MealPeriod.value = "Lunch", Fields!Burger_Lunch_Type.value, Fields!Burger_Dinner_Type.value) & " and " & (select top row from dataset given the correct type field and Item ID)
```

The cell should look like: Table1.Type and Table2.Breadtype AKA Bacon Burger and Whole Wheat.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the dreaded Lookup function for this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx

I say dreaded because it is notoriously tricky to code and debug.  I've even seen a case where a failed Lookup caused the entire row to disappear!

The Lookup target dataset itself should not use the parameters required for the Lookup - it's purpose is to return all the possible rows needed by the Lookup function.

If you need to use two columns as the key to your lookup, you can concatenate them e.g.

`Fields!Burger_Lunch_Type.value & "|" & Fields!ItemID.value`

Good luck!